Android app fails to load localized resources (values-uk, values-ru) on certain devices depending on system locale
I have an Android app that supports multiple languages: English, Ukrainian and Russian. The app works perfectly when installed directly from Android Studio onto any device. However, when the app is downloaded from the Google Play Store, strange behavior occurs only on some devices:
If the device locale is set to Ukrainian, the app loads all languages fine (UA, RU, EN).
If the device locale is set to Russian, the app loads only RU and EN, but Ukrainian resources (values-uk) are not loaded.
If the device locale is set to English, neither RU nor UA resources are loaded—only English works.
I have tested this thoroughly and included logs that show the locale being set properly at runtime, so I don't suspect an issue with the code logic itself.
Here’s the relevant code for changing the app language:
private fun changeAppLanguage(selectedLanguage: String) {
    val languages = resources.getStringArray(R.array.languages)
    when (selectedLanguage) {
        languages[0] -> {
            updateLanguageSettings("uk")
        }
        languages[1] -> {
            updateLanguageSettings("ru")
        }
        languages[2] -> {
            updateLanguageSettings("en")
        }
        else -> {
            updateLanguageSettings("en")
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("AppBundleLocaleChanges")
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
private fun updateLanguageSettings(language: String) {
    saveLanguage(language)
    val locale = Locale(language)
    val config = resources.configuration
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    config.setLocale(locale)
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
    updateViews()
}

Here’s the structure of my resource folders (see image):
(https://i.sstatic.net/5StXJlHO.png)

Verified that all localized resources are correctly included in the decompiled APK (nothing is missing).

Added the following to build.gradle to ensure the resources are explicitly packaged:


resourceConfigurations += listOf("en", "ru", "uk", "uk-rUA")
resConfigs("en", "ru", "uk", "uk-rUA")


Logged the locale values to ensure the app sets them correctly at runtime:
Locale.getDefault() returns correct values (uk, ru, etc.).
resources.configuration.locale also reflects the desired locale.

Despite this, the behavior remains inconsistent depending on the device's default system locale.

"Verified that all localized resources are correctly included in the decompiled APK" -- is that what you are shipping, though? Most new apps are distributed as Android app bundles (AABs), which are specifically designed for being split into pieces along resource set lines. I have never shipped an app that attempted to use the code in your updateLanguageSettings(), but you might need to take some steps to ensure that all users of your app get all languages at install time.

After much troubleshooting, I discovered that the issue was related to how Google Play handles Android App Bundles (AABs). By default, when you publish an app using the AAB format, Google Play splits the app into multiple APKs to optimize for the user's device. This process, known as dynamic delivery, minimizes app size by only including resources relevant to the user's device settings (such as locale, screen density, etc.).
Root Cause: If the user's device locale is set to English, Google Play may not deliver Ukrainian (values-uk) or Russian (values-ru) resources to the device to save space. This is why the app failed to load all resources correctly for certain locales when installed from the Play Store, even though it worked perfectly when installed directly from Android Studio (which installs all resources).
Solution: To ensure that all language resources are included in the installed app, you need to disable language splitting in the build.gradle file. This can be done by adding the following configuration under the android section:
    android {

    // other configurations

        bundle {
            language {
               enableSplit = false
            }
        }
    }

By setting enableSplit to false, you ensure that all language resources are included in the app, regardless of the user's locale. This resolves the issue by preventing Google Play from excluding any language resources during dynamic delivery.
Additional Information: A detailed explanation of Android App Bundles and resource splitting can be found in this article. It provides valuable insights into how app bundles work and the options available for handling resource configurations.
Special thanks to @CommonsWare for pointing me in the right direction with their comment:

"Verified that all localized resources are correctly included in the decompiled APK" -- is that what you are shipping, though? Most new apps are distributed as Android app bundles (AABs), which are specifically designed for being split into pieces along resource set lines. I have never shipped an app that attempted to use the code in your updateLanguageSettings(), but you might need to take some steps to ensure that all users of your app get all languages at install time.

